# Read Uncommitted For Ria Service

Tags: wcf-ria-services

Is it possible to have a read uncommitted in ria service load operation? Or should I convert my load operation to invoke instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If with Read uncommitted you're talking about sql transaction isolation, the answer is yes, no problem, thst's not related to wcf ria services at all. It's something you set in your server data layer.